# Casting to parent changes object reference?

Tags: java, spring, redis

I'm doing some work with jesque, workers and pipelines. I'm ok with that; the thing is that I have a new feature. I have a class named `FileAnalysis`, so it has some common attributes, but it is not abstract enough; it is still very focused on the task it was made for.

I made another feature before and was able to reuse this `FileAnalysis`. But this time there are new key properties for the feature I'm working on, so I created a new object `ContactFileAnalysis` with the additional properties.

A `FileAnalysis` consists of the main object, which is then parsed to JSON and stored in redis. This is done through a manager; this manager reads/writes to redis, and recreates the `FileAnalysis` object. There is a support object to update the state of the file analysis in a pipeline; it's called:

```
FileAnalysisUpdater(FileAnalysis).
```

If I make a new manager which is able to handle `ContactFileAnalysis`, this objects holds new properties and the new manager will store them in redis correctly. Then it calls the updater in a pipeline. What I want to achieve is to invoke

```
ContactFileAnalysis contactFileAnalysis;
updater.Update((FileAnalysis) contactFileAnalysis);
```

When I cast to a parent object and the pipeline is done, will `contactFileAnalysis` be updated by the updater? Or does this cast change the object reference and therefore no change is reflected?

I want to reuse this functionality because there are no changes in it; the behavior is the same, the information is the same; I just need to propagate new information, and to do so I persist it in redis, but from there on it's the same; the updater doesn't need anything from my new object.

P.S.: I know it is safer to write every involved object again and make sure it works with the new FileAnalysis, but this means a lot of code for a feature that is hardly used and not that important. Also, I work for this project and it's not easy to approve a PR of 4k lines of code.

Comment: A cast *never* changes the actual object/reference in Java: it is only the 'lens' through which static-typing is applied. ("casts" on primitives are conversions and are not applicable to the previous statement.)

Comment: thanks for your comment, is there a link to docs where i can read more on it? i almost done with my code and about to test it, but i want to read more about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user2864740 pointed out in a comment, casting an object reference never changes the reference. You can test this easily enough:

```
Object obj = null;
String str = "foo";
obj = (Object) str; // Unnecessary! See below.
System.out.println ("Is str == obj? " + (str == obj));
```

However, that casting to the parent is likely unnecessary. Hopefully you declared `ContactFileAnalysis` to be a subclass of `FileAnalysis`:

```
public class ContactFileAnalysis extends FileAnalysis
```

If so, then any reference to an instance of `ContactFileAnalysis` is always considered a reference to an instance of `FileAnalysis`. In fact, it's also a reference to an instance of `FileAnalysis`' superclass, and so on up the line (to `java.lang.Object`, the parent of all java objects). Which means my cast to `Object` in the sample code was unnecessary:

```
obj = str; // This works, and is considered proper style.
```

It's also unnecessary to cast it to pass it to `updater.Update()`. (Another style note: methods should start with a lowercase letter.)

```
updater.Update(contactFileAnalysis); // Probably fine. See below.
```

Note that if you didn't declare `ContactFileAnalysis` to be a subclass of `FileAnalysis`, you *will* have to cast it. (This could happen if you instead had a class that implemented two interfaces, had a reference to an instance of it typed to one of those interfaces, and wanted to pass it to a method that took an instance of the other.)

Another note: if for some reason you had two methods as follows:

```
public void update (FileAnalysis fa) { /* code */ }
public void update (ContactFileAnalysis cfa) { /* ugh */ }
```

And you made a reference to a `ContactFileAnalysis` instance, and passed that to your updater:

```
ContactFileAnalysis myCFA = new ContactFileAnalysis();
updater.update (myCFA);
```

It'll use the *second* `update` - the one defined to take a CFA. Cast it, however:

```
updater.update ((FileAnalysis) myCFA);
```

and it'll use the *first* `update`. Same thing happens if you set a `FileAnalysis` variable to it.

```
FileAnalysis myFA = myCFA;
updater.update (myFA); // uses the first update, even though it's a CFA
```

Hopefully you understand why. If not, check out the [official documentation on inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).